# Command button Issue with Lightning Experience

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a command button on Visulaforce Page (I have applied LDS) where I am calling an outh URI, where we get screen of Allow/Deny to access this application for oAuth permission.

```
<apex:commandButton value="{!IF(iConStatus.Connected__c,$Label.Refresh_Btn_Lbl,$Label.Connect_Btn_Lbl)}" 
        action="{!connect}" rendered="{!NOT(isEdit)}" reRender="oAuthURIWindowOpener,adminForm" styleClass="secondaryButton"/>
```

I have used outputpanel to rerender this part , here is the code, where I have set attribute `"_self"` to open that in same window, in command button action I am calling a page Reference using which I need to redirect user to Same page where he hit the button.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="oAuthURIWindowOpener">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    goToOAuthURI("{!URLENCODE(oAuthURI)}");

    function goToOAuthURI(oAuthURI) {
      if(oAuthURI != null && oAuthURI != "") {
           window.open(""+oAuthURI, "_self");
      }
    }

    function inputLimiter(e, fVal) {
      var AllowableCharacters = '0123456789';
      var k = document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
      if (k!=13 && k!=8 && k!=0){
        if ((e.ctrlKey==false) && (e.altKey==false)) {
          return ((AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1) && (fVal.value.length < 9));
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

In classic view it works fine, but when I enable lightning experience it get opened in new tab and after clicking on Allow button , User is redirected to new tab of browser and page gets displayed without having header or footer.

Here are the screenshots.

1. Visualforce Page having "Refresh Connection" command button, Initial look of VF page when opened in Lightning experience.
   [image]
2. When I hit "Refresh Connection" it opens up oAuth URI for granting permission in new tab.
   [image]
3. After Clicking on Allow button, it get redirected in new tab with same page having no header and footer.
   [image]

Anything special that I need to take care of while redirecting user using Page-reference in lightning experience so that page get opened in same window.

Does external link gets always opened in new window in Lightning Experience?

Please advise solution if any.

Comment: did you try `_blank` - just a thought as trying different options is always first on my "how can I make this work" list when troubleshooting.

Comment: @Eric Yes I tried that, that too opens in new tab ! I want to open it in same window.